# Filling a textbox with limited size

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I have a textbox control from DevExpress and we cant allow more characters beyond its capacity. The problem is that the input string is xml formatted and can have multiple fonts. If the font size increases, the maximum number of characters decrease.

My first thought is counting by line, because lines are measurable despite font size. But the column I could not see a way.

How could I fill this textbox taking in consideration the string font e xml tags ?

Comment: Probably need to measure size of the rendered text and see if it fits inside the size of the textbox usable area.

Comment: Are you using an edit mask, or no?

Comment: Can't help you, but there is a devexpress tag you may want to add to your post

Comment: Hi tony, i guess your sugestion is the most confortable I'm with. I'm thinking in searching for some property that allow me to set the DevExpress textbox limit, without scroll bars and hidden caracters. So it'll only show the delimited area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Exception Handling to figure it out for you:

```
bool flag = false;
int count = line.Length;

do
{
    try
    {
       txt.Text = line.SubString(0, count);
       flag = true;
    }
    catch(TheException)
    {
       count--;
    }
}
while(!flag);
```

This works if you are getting an exception for putting in too long a line.

Comment: Hi chuck, thx for the answer. Unfortunately I wont be able to use it. As font size increases the max lines number decreases. My mistake = ]. Lets see what the others have to say.